# log4j header every N lines

Tags: log4j

I need to add a log4j header and footer every N lines of the log. I know how to specify a log4j header/footer by overriding the getHeader()/getFooter() methods of the PatternLayout class. But, this seems to be limited to including the header/footer only once (top/bottom) of each rolling log file (daily in my case).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Subclassing the layout class will not be enough. What will work is if you also create your own subclass of the appender, RollingFileAppender in your case I presume. You can override the append() method so that it counts the lines written (well in fact the records written) to the file, then invoke writeHeader()/writeFooter() based on the number of lines.

The following implementation allows you to set the frequency at which the header will be written in the configuration file, via the `headerFrequency` attribute:

```
public class MyRollingFileAppender extends RollingFileAppender {
  // number of lines after which the header is written
  private int headerFrequency = -1;
  // Count of lines written by the appender
  private int nbLines = 0;

  @Override
  public void append(final LoggingEvent event) {
    super.append(event);
    nbLines++;
    if ((headerFrequency > 0) &&
        (nbLines % headerFrequency == 0)) {
      writeHeader();
    }
  }

  public int getHeaderFrequency() {
    return headerFrequency;
  }

  public void setHeaderFrequency(final int headerFrequency) {
    this.headerFrequency = headerFrequency;
  }
}
```

The following implementation of the layout allows you to actually set the header text in the log4j configuration file as well:

```
public class MyLayout extends PatternLayout {
  // The header
  private String header = null;

  @Override
  public String getHeader() {
    return header;
  }

  public void setHeader(String header) {
    this.header = header;
  }
}
```

Then you can use this in the log4j configuration as follows:

```
log4j.appender.CUSTOM=test.MyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CUSTOM.HeaderFrequency=100
... other appender properties ...
log4j.appender.CUSTOM.layout=test.MyLayout
log4j.appender.CUSTOM.layout.Header=***** This is my header *****\n
... other layout properties ...

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CUSTOM
```

Comment: Good to hear. If this resolves your problem, you might want to upvote the answer

Comment: It won't let me, says I need at least 15 reputations.